# Compile Python debug and pip install debug libraries

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, pip, pyside, pycrypto

I am trying to debug some mysterious crashes in my PySide application. I am currently on Python 2.7 in Windows and want to build the debug versions of Python and PySide to help debug. I followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/VS2012) to build the debug version of Python using MSVC 2013. The build works for the most part, with some of the libraries I don't care about not able to compile.

I copied the relevant files over to c:\python27_d using the same instructions in the link above and set up a virtual environment for it. However, when I try to easy_install or pip install libraries such as paramiko or pycrypto, I would get link errors:

```
winrand.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_InitModule4 referenced in function _initwinr
andom

build\lib.win32-2.7-pydebug\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\winrandom.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

In general, how do I install libraries or modules for the debug version of Python? I apologize for asking such a broad question, but I am not familiar with the internals of how Python to know where to find the unresolved links.

Comment: May I suggest you take a step back into the original problem and reevaluate whether building a new version of Python on Windows is the best step? Can you reproduce your bug on another platform? Can you describe your bug so we can offer a better solution? Is it still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

cd into `C:\Python27\Scripts` then run:

```
pip install PySide --use-wheel -f https://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/pyside/
```